# Celery, calling delay with countdown

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to understand how celery works

In my django application in `tasks.py` file I have created one task:

```
@celery.shared_task(default_retry_delay=2 * 60, max_retries=2)
def my_task(param1, param2):
    # There are some operations
```

I call this task by using this code:

```
my_task.delay(param1, param2)
```

Inside of this `my_task` there is one condition where this task should be started again **but after one minute delay**

I have found that there are some kind of [ETA and countdown](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) for tasks, but their examples are only with `apply_async`

Is it possible to use some kind countdown for `delay`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From [basic part of celery Calling documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#basics)

> ```
> delay(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> Shortcut to send a task message, but **doesn’t support execution
>   options**.
>
> So delay is clearly convenient, but if you want to set additional
>   execution options you have to use **apply_async**.

As documentation states `delay` cannot be used with additional options set so you should just convert your call into `apply_async`

If you want to add execution options, the docs suggest you use a signature. e.g:

```
my_task.s(arg1, arg2).apply_async(countdown=60)
```

Comment: So you mean if I call it `my_task.delay(param1, param2)` I need to use this: `my_task.apply_async((param1, param2), countdown=60)` ?

Comment: Running 'AsyncResult' and 'Signature' isn't supported

Answer (score 28):

Just to add to iklinac's answer. This is how you would call the task using apply_async()

```
my_task.apply_async(args=(param1, param2), countdown=60)
```

or

```
my_task.apply_async(kwargs={'param1':param1, 'param2':param2}, countdown=60)
```

The second option will really come in handy if you are using a tool like Flower for monitoring. You can look at [Celery tasks best practices](https://pawelzny.com/python/celery/2017/08/14/celery-4-tasks-best-practices/) page for other tips.